# On identities and congruences involving the harmonic mean of odd perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, congruences, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

I would like to know if my calculations were rights and if you want to deduce other different interesting congruences following my approach.

**On assumption** (notice that it isn't the usually accepted conjecture, I am saying that the belief is that there exists no odd perfect numbers; but it is required suppose such hypothesis to try deduce something about odd perfect numbers and also in an hypothetical proof by contradiction) **that there exists an odd perfect number** $n$, then its [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_divisor_number)

$$H(n)=\frac{n\sigma_{0}(n)}{\sigma(n)},$$
**is integer** (see the genuine definition from previous **Wikipedia**'s article) where $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d$ is the **sum of divisors function** and $\sigma_0(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}1$ the **number of such positive divisors**. Please, notice thus from this factorization that this arithmetic function is also **multiplicative**.

> **Claim 1.** If there are no mistakes in my calculations I can deduce by substitution of $H(n)$ in the particular value of $H(2^an)$, where $a\geq 1$ is an integer, the following identity that holds on assumption that $n$ is an odd perfect number
>   $$(2^{a+1}-1)H(2^an)=2^a(a+1)H(n).$$

And also using **Euler-Fermat Theorem** with specialization $a=\phi(n)$, where $\phi(m)$ is the **Euler's totient function**, one gets the following first statement, and secondly with the specialization $a=n$ and dividing (without Euler-Fermat) the second one, of the following

> **Claim 2.** On assumption that there exists an odd perfect number $n$, then $$(2^{\phi(n)+1}-1)H(2^{\phi(n)}n)\equiv(\phi(n)+1)H(n)\text{ mod }n,$$
>   and 
>   $$(2^{n+1}-1)H(2^n n)\equiv 2^nH(n)\text{ mod }n.$$

(**Also was fixed a typo.**)

Then

> **Question 1.** What's about previous claims? Can you provide us detatils to **show that my calculations were rights, or is there a mistake?** Also you are welcome to discuss in comments if those claims are interesting.

The following is to encourage to study this kind of questions, isn't required a full answer (only a contribution as an answer, a reference, hints...) for the following

> **Question 2.** As a secondary question: can you provide us different congruences from same approach? I am saying if it is possible deduce more interesting recurrences, relationships or congruences for the harmonic mean of an odd perfect number (maybe you can assume different primes that don't divide $n$, or to use that the harmonic mean is multiplicative in a different way, I was thinking what's about two odd perfect numbers, being coprime...).

**Many thanks users!**

Comment: Also it's possible deduce $$(H(n))^2H(n+1)H(n-1)\sigma(n-1)\sigma(n+1)=(\frac{n^2-1}{2})(\sigma_0(n))^2\sigma_0(n+1)\sigma_0(n-1),$$ where $\frac{n^2-1}{2}$ is integer.

Comment: I am waiting the proof verification from some user and if he/she can deduce some interesting identities, and why his/her identities could be  potentially useful. I've deduced one more: let $N=p^{4\lambda+1}m^2$ the **eulerian form** of an **odd perfect number** then $$2\sigma_0(2^{p-1})H(p^{4\lambda }m^2)=\sigma_0(p^{4\lambda}m^2).$$ On the other hand I've found the equivalence: $n\geq 1$ is **perfect** if and only if $$\sum_{d\mid n}(d+n/d)^2=2\sigma_2(n)+4nH(n),$$ where $\sigma_2(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d^2$. 
(One can write $\sigma_0(n)\sigma(n)$ instead of $4nH(n)$ in previous equivalence).

Comment: Many thanks to you and other users for this edit @2015